# Getting 'Failed to allocate memory' while parsing large XML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have been facing an issue with "failed to allocate memory" while parsing it using Nokogiri. For that I have written following code.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
f = File.open("/my_pplications/XML/one.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)    
stack = Hash.new
doc.children.each do |x|  
  x.children.each do |sx|
   sx.children.each do |v|      
     stack[v.name] = v.text      
   end 
  end 
end
```

Here if the `one.xml` file is `smaller` in size, I am able to parse and get everything.
But if that file is `too large(more than 700MB)`, I am getting the error like `"[FATAL] failed to allocate memory"`. So how can I parse complete large XML file.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Besides adding memory you mean? You could try Nokogiri::XML::SAX

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728046/how-to-use-sax-with-nokogiri

Answer (score 4):

Nokogiri::XML builds an in memory representation of the entire document so uses up much more memory than the on disk size of the document. It is then easy to iterate through it and the use xpath or css queries.

The alternative is to use nokogiri's SAX parser. A sax parser has hardly any memory overhead because it's not storing the entire document in memory: it just walks through the document, telling the object you provide about interesting events, such as tag foo has started, I found some text, the foo tag has closed etc.

It is in general a little more work to use this rather than the higher level interfaces, but you can devour enormous XML files this way