# How to parse dynamic XML with a SAX parser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sax

Scenario:

- Large (dynamic) xml files being uploaded by users.
- We need to map the xml to our own database structure.
- We need to use a SAX parser (or something like it) because of memory issues when parsing large XML files.

We currently use https://github.com/craigambrose/sax_stream for parsing XML's that all have the same structure.

For a new feature, we need to parse XML with unknown contents.

How would one use a SAX parser when the xml nodes are different each time ?

I've tried using https://github.com/soulcutter/saxerator, especially the `at_depth()` function could come in handy to collect the elements at a certain depth, after that we could get the elements inside a node by using the `for_tag()` function. Based on this info we maybe could create a mapping on the fly

If a SAX parser isn't an option, are there any alternatives for parsing very large (dynamic) XML files?

Comment: What means _dynamic_ in case of a file?

Comment: With dynamic I mean that the XML file is very different every time. The node names and structure are always different.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728046/how-to-use-sax-with-nokogiri for a nokogiri example of sax.